# Teleric RadEditor - Can I register client OnClientSubmit events in the skin file?

Tags: telerik, client-side, radeditor

There is a known issue with the Telerik RadEditor that causes odd character insertions, as [documented here](http://feedback.telerik.com/Project/108/Feedback/Details/88012-fix-when-some-bold-text-is-being-saved-into-a-database-unexpected-question-mark).

The work around requires the insertion of a client-side script to strip out the offending character in the OnClientSubmit event.

We use this control in many places and have three styles defined in our skins file for it.  We also derive a custom control from the RadEditor in a custom control we call RichEdit.

The question is - will this approach work to guarantee that all instances of our RichEdit control receive the required client-side event?

1) In the RichEdit.cs OnLoad, register a client script block containing the required javascript function
2) In the skin file, add the required OnClientSubmit method call to each skin?

So - will it work?   And if not, what DO I need to do?

Answer (score -1):

And the answer is yes.

Adding a call to this method in the page load section:

```
    private void AddRichEditGarbageCharacterWorkaround()
    {
        string scriptName = "RadEditorOnClientSubmit";
        Type csType = GetType();

        ClientScriptManager csm = Page.ClientScript;
        if (!csm.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(csType, scriptName))
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
            sb.Append("\tfunction RadEditorStripGarbage(editor, args) {");
            sb.Append("\t\tvar html = editor.get_html();");
            sb.Append("\t\thtml = html.replace(/\u200b/g, \"\");");
            sb.Append("\t\teditor.set_html(html);");
            sb.Append("\t\t}");
            sb.Append("</script>");

            csm.RegisterClientScriptBlock(csType, scriptName, sb.ToString());
        }
    }
```

And adding this to the skin:

```
<nt:RichEdit runat="server" SkinID="SpellCheckOnly" ...
OnClientSubmit="RadEditorStripGarbage" >
```

Successfully added the code and the hook to every instance.